# Equivalent of `util.inspect` in Deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno, inspect

Does Deno have a utility function that dumps a Object or primitive to a string like Node.js `util.inspect`?

For example in Node.js I create an json object and want to dump out its contents in Node:

```
> m = {k1:'v1', k2:'v2'}
{ k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2' }
> util.inspect(m)
'{ k1: \'v1\', k2: \'v2\' }'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deno's equivalent of Node's `util.inspect` is `Deno.inspect`.

For example in the deno REPL:

```
> m = {k1:'v1', k2:'v2'}
{ k1: "v1", k2: "v2" }
> Deno.inspect(m)
{ k1: "v1", k2: "v2" }
```

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, if you want to override to return your own results from `Deno.inspect`, you can add a `Deno.customInspect` method to your classes like so:

```
class someClass {
    // code ...

    [Symbol.for("Deno.customInspect")]() {
        return 'any ol string';
    }

}
```

Here's the [documentation](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.inspect) for `Deno.inspect` and `Deno.customInspect`

Comment: That is slick! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This has been deprecated since Deno 1.19. See my answer for a more up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 2):

Generally use `Deno.inspect(someObject)`.

In case you want to customize the string representation of `Deno.inspect` for a specific class, since Deno 1.19, you are supposed to implement something like the following:

```
class MyClass {

  // …

  [Symbol.for("Deno.customInspect")]() {
    return "custom string representation;
  }

  // …
}
```

Objects displayed using `console.log(someObject)` will also be affected by this.

Documentation can be found [here](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.customInspect).

Note that the version shown by @Lukalot is deprecated since Deno 1.19 and might therefore stop to work in future versions.